# how to hide infomation link append bottom browser when page load

Tags: html, css

I want to hide all information link when load page append bottom in browser when load page.

sample:

[image: sample]

Comment: my comment : What ? . please be more specific about what you want

Comment: So you want to hide the "Waiting for stackoverflow.com..." message?

Comment: @MihaiT: in my website, i want to hide image link store on aws s3. I use aws s3 to store image.
i try rewirte url image from `https://exfranshare.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/listing/image/3564/logo.jpg` to `http://mydomain/uploads/listings/image/3564/logo.jpg` and i use htaccess to redirect 'mydomain..' to 'amazon...'
but when load page i want to display `mydomain`  instead for `aws.s3.amazon....` in bottom browers.